# Definition of upper hemicontinuity of a correspondence.

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity, fixed-point-theorems

When using and examining Kakutani's fixed-point theorem, I've got a question about upper hemicontinuity.

A correspondence $f:X\rightarrow2^Y$ is a point-to-set mapping.

One way to define upper hemicontinuity of $f$ is as below.

Given such a $f$, $f$ is said to be upper hemicontinuous at $\bar{x}$ if for every open set $V$ such that $f(\bar{x})\subset V$, there exists an open set $U$ such that $\bar{x}\in U$ and $x\in U$ implies $f(x)\subset V$.

However, I once read a different definition of upper hemicontinuity on a textbook:

Given such a correspondence $f$, $f$ is said to be upper hemicontinuous at $\bar{x}$ if for every sequence $\{x_n\}\rightarrow\bar{x}$ and for every open set $V$ such that $f(\bar{x})\subset V$, there exists an $N\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(x_n)\subset V,~\forall n\geq N$.

Can someone help me prove that these two definitions are equivalent?

(It's easy to prove from the former to the latter, but what about the other way?)

Comment: I am not sure that ([tag:special-functions]) is a suitable tag for this question; see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_functions) for the usual meaning of the phrase *special functions*. Multivalued functions seem more like ([tag:general-topology]) to me.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an open set $V\subset Y$, denote $\widetilde  V =\{x: f(x)\subset V\}$.

The first definition says: if $\bar x\in \widetilde  V$, then $\bar x$ is an interior point of $\widetilde  V$.

The second definition says: if $\bar x\in \widetilde  V$ and $x_n\to x$, then $x_n\in \widetilde  V$ for all large $n$.

Now all multi-valuedness disappears from the view: we are staring at the sequential characterization of interior points. Indeed, the following three are equivalent in first-countable topological spaces:

1. $x$ is an interior point of $A$.
2. $x$ is **not** in the closure of $A^c$.
3. $x$  is **not**  the limit of any sequence   in $A^c$.

Comment: Excuse me, what are "sequential characterization of interior points" and "first-countable topological spaces"? Could you explain them in more detail? Or are there any links to definitions of them?

Comment: @RitaTseng See Wikipedia for [First-countable spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-countable_space). By sequential characterization of interior points the answerer probably means this: *A point $x$ is an interior point of $A$ if and only if for every sequence $(x_n)$ which converges to $x$ there is an $n_0$ such that $x_n\in A$ for $n\ge n_0$.* More frequently you see the characterization of closed subsets using closedness under limits of sequences, this is more-or-less just a reformulation. This is not true in all topological spaces, but it is true in first-countable spaces.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for your answer. So I think we can conclude that the sequential characterization of interior points (even of other mathematical terms if they make sense) is simply the other version of definition of interior points using sequences.

Comment: @RitaTseng Basically yes, with the caveat that this cannot be done in arbitrary space. (If the space we are working with is first countable, we are safe.)

Comment: @HowAboutaNiceBigC So if X, Y are metric spaces, then the second definition implies that if x-bar is in V-tilde, then any sequence {x_n} converging to x-bar is a sequence in V-tilde. Hence x-bar isn't the limit of any sequence in the complement of V-tilde, which implies that x-bar is an interior point of V-tilde. Then there exists a neighborhood U of x-bar such that U's a subset of V-tilde. Thus for all x in U, f(x) is a subset of V, which is the first definition. It completes the equivalence of these two definitions. Is my reasoning right?

Comment: @RitaTseng Yes, this is correct.